# Switch betweeen method versions

Tags: c++, flags

I need to rewrite some c++ classes and I would like to be able to switch between the new code and the old code (reliable and fast). What would be good options to do so? In general I need some kind of switch that decides what to do, like:

```
int foo::bar()
{
   if (yesUseNew == true)
  {
    return 1 + 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 1 + 2;
  }
}
```

HOW and where could i set yesUseNew? It should be useable in Debug-Build and in Release and it should be applied directly. So reading some xml-Config would be to late.

The attempt, with two code-versions directly in the methods, is only an example. At this point I am not sure on which abstraction level I will do this. The primary question is actually HOW I can distinguish between the versions (fast).

Thanks!

Comment: where do you want to set it?

Comment: Would you like to switch before or after compiling your code?

Comment: @Lanting At this point I am searching for implementation ideas, so options for both would be great :)

Comment: you can use preprocessor and then in your debug version compile with -D OLDVERSION=1 / -D OLDVERSION=0 to choose if you want to use old/new version. -D FLAG=3 (for instance) will replace all FLAG by 3 in the text of all the code you try to compile with this flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I see the following alternatives :

1. At compile time with #define

e.g:

```
#define V1  //Comment this line if you want V2. You can also define it on the command line of your compiler

void myfunction() {
#ifdef V1
//V1 Implementation
#else
//V2 Impl
#endif
```

2. At runtime with env variables for example

This means you can switch without recompiling.

```
if (std::getenv("V1"))
    //V1 Code
else
    //V2 Code
```

3. Add a configuration option to your app, either in the command line or the config file if it has one. If the dual behaviour will last this is the way to go

Comment: then use -D V1 as option for your compiler or don't use it to switch between versions

Comment: @IaenNoCode is `-D V1` the alternative to just commenting out the define?

Comment: @rene `-D` is a command line parameter most compilers provide to define pre-processor variables for as long as the compiler runs, i.e. as long as compiling the files you provided to it. MSVC might require `/D` instead, not sure if it additionally supports `-D`. You can even give a value with (`-D V1=1`), which would allow you to test for `#if V1` instead (where undefined macros are resolved to 0). If you use it, you'd drop the `#define` within the file entirely, you just provide the parameter or not (or give it appropriate value), according to the result you intend to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use macros with `#ifdef` clauses to separate code parts:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NEW

int main()
{
#ifdef NEW
    {
        std::cout << "NEW" << std::endl;
    }

#else
    {
        std::cout << "OLD" << std::endl;
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Prints `NEW` if `#define NEW` is specified

Answer (score 0):

For the compile-time option the `#define` approach has been mentioned already in other answers, so skipping this one here; but I yet throw in polymorphism as an *alternative* for the run-time solution already provided:

```
class Runtime
{
public:
    // designed to invoke undefined behaviour
    // you might test for existance and throw on negative result instead
    static Runtime& instance()
    {
        // TODO: only thread-safe if writing pointers is atomic
        //       otherwise you might need to care for
        //       (unfortunately `std::unique_ptr` cannot be wrapped
        //        in a std::atomic, so you need to do handle on your own)
        return *s_instance;
    }

   virtual void theFunction() = 0;
    // yet others

protected:
    Runtime() { } // wouldn't want to construct outside the classes

    virtual ~Runtime() { } // std::unique_ptr needs to be friend
                           // for having this protected

    template <typename RT>
    void init()
    {
        // TODO: yet needs to be made thread-safe!
        if(s_instance)
        {
            // appropriate error handling, possibly throw!
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    // variables/helper functions needed for both variants

private:
    // some of might be private if not to be used from deriving classes

    static inline std::unique_ptr<Runtime> s_instance;
};

class OldRuntime : public Runtime
{
public:
    static void init()
    {
        RunTime::init<OldRuntime>();
    }

    void theFunction() override { /* old behaviour */ }
private:
    OldRuntime() { }  // templated init needs to be friend!

    // variables, helper functions, ... needed for the old approach
};

class NewRuntime : public Runtime
{
public:
    static void init()
    {
        RunTime::init<OldRuntime>();
    }

    void theFunction() override { /* new behaviour */ }

private:
   NewRuntime() { } // templated init needs to be friend!

    // variables, helper functions, ... needed for the old approach
};
```

In above code any thread-safety concerns can be omitted if it is expected to be only ever called before any other threads have been started (or these have terminated already) – this then needs to be clearly documented.

You now still need to decide when to use which variant. Environment variable has been mentioned already – this is only an option if you are fine with any instance already running retaining the behaviour it installed at startup time. If you want to get the behaviour updated then this aproach is *not suitable*!

A command line parameter in constrast can allow you to define which behaviour to use for every instance *individually* and you don't need to 'spoil' any environments at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's common practice to add macros that expand to `0` or `1`. You can provide a default value:

```cpp
#ifndef CONFIG_NEW
# define CONFIG_NEW 1
#endif
```

Whatever build system you use will provide some way of defining these macros by passing a compiler flag, `-DCONFIG_NEW=1` or to generate a `config.h` file which defines these flags.

Note that with most build systems, it's possible to have multiple build directories that have different configurations. With CMake for example this is can be done by invoking `cmake` multiple times with different build directories and different flags.