# Using typedef to define the base class

Tags: c++, typedef

Based on my previous question ([Switch betweeen method versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569199/switch-betweeen-method-versions/73569303?noredirect=1#comment129917195_73569303)) I would like to know if the following attempt would makes any sense if I have an old class implementation someBase1 (which is used in legacy code very very often) and I would like to replace the class by a new class (someBase2) with the same API, but would be able to switch back to old version if needed:

```
//someBase1 and someBase2 have the same public API
class someBase1 {

};

class someBase2 {

};


#ifdef V1
typedef someBase1 someType;
#else
typedef someBase2 someType;
#endif

class someDerived :
  public someType
{

};
```

It looks a bit odd to me and I can't find something for that (or at least I don't know the correct wording for the search...)

Are there maybe some more usual methods to achive this?

Comment: This will work, yes.

Comment: That would work. But unless "V2" (or what it might be) does things completely different perhaps rename the "V1" class, create a new class and have it inherit from the "V1" class, and then create an alias to the old name? Something like `class someBaseV1 { }; class someBaseV2 : public someBaseV1 { }; using someBase = someBaseV2;` Then the derived classes can continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: Be careful, though. You'll need to make sure that `V1` symbol is defined in every library that your `someDerived` class header gets used.

Comment: "_but would be able to switch back to old version if needed_": You will only be able to switch if you simultaneously switch it in all translation units using `someDerived`. Trying to mix between the two will cause the program to have undefined behavior because of ODR violation.